# Difference between these array shapes in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the difference between 2 arrays whose shapes are-

**(442,1)**  and  **(442,)** ?

Printing both of these produces an identical output, but when I check for equality **==**, I get a 2D vector like this-

```
array([[ True, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ...,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: unutbu makes the key insight as a short comment below. To expand: numpy array shapes are returned as python [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) which, unlike a python list, can't straightforwardly be written down with a single entry: `(442)` would just evaluate to the integer `422` , unlike `[422]`.  The extra comma is just an aspect of python tuple syntax for single-element tuples to distinguish them from integers, not anything specific to do with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

An array of shape `(442, 1)` is 2-dimensional. It has 442 rows and 1 column.

An array of shape `(442, )` is 1-dimensional and consists of 442 elements.

Note that their reprs should look different too. There is a difference in the number and placement of parenthesis:

```
In [7]: np.array([1,2,3]).shape
Out[7]: (3,)

In [8]: np.array([[1],[2],[3]]).shape
Out[8]: (3, 1)
```

---

Note that you could use `np.squeeze` to remove axes of length 1:

```
In [13]: np.squeeze(np.array([[1],[2],[3]])).shape
Out[13]: (3,)
```

---

[NumPy broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) allow new axes to be automatically added *on the left* when needed. So `(442,)` can broadcast to `(1, 442)`. And axes of length 1 can broadcast to any length. So
when you test for equality between an array of shape `(442, 1)` and an array of shape `(442, )`, the second array gets promoted to shape `(1, 442)` and then the two arrays expand their axes of length 1 so that they both become broadcasted arrays of shape `(442, 442)`. This is why when you tested for equality the result was a boolean array of shape `(442, 442)`.

```
In [15]: np.array([1,2,3]) == np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
Out[15]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [16]: np.array([1,2,3]) == np.squeeze(np.array([[1],[2],[3]]))
Out[16]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to data mining and couldn't understand the ([value], ) syntax as opposed to the normal ([value]) syntax for array shapes. That extra comma was making things convoluted.

Comment: The comma in `(422, )` indicates the expression is a tuple. It's a tuple with one element inside. Without the comma, `(422)` gets evaluated as the integer `422`. The shape of an array is always a tuple.

Comment: Are arrays of size (1,442) and (442,) the same then?

Comment: @bikashg yes there are identical