# Tensorflow placeholder declaration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to convert a [tutorial](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) from Keras to TF. 
I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/Development/google/python/machine_learning/deep_learning/exercise1_tf.py", line 64, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 975, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (768,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

This seems to be related in how I'm passing the target labels and how my placeholder value is declared.
When I return the labels I have this:

```
>>> dataset[:, 8].shape
(768,)
>>> dataset[:, 0:8].shape
(768, 8)
```

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print("Tensorflow version: " + tf.__version__)
tf.set_random_seed(0)

FILENAME = 'pima-indians-diabetes.csv'
_LEARNING_RATE = 0.003
_NUM_FEATURES = 8
_NUM_LABELS = 1
_NUM_EPOCHS = 150
_BATCH_SIZE = 10


def import_data(filename):
    if filename:
        dataset = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=",")
        return dataset[:, 0:8], dataset[:, 8]


# create placeholder. Dataset contains _NUM_FEATURES features:
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, _NUM_FEATURES])
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, _NUM_LABELS])  # Placeholder for correct answers

# weights and biases
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([_NUM_FEATURES, _NUM_LABELS],
                                 mean=0,
                                 stddev=0.1,
                                 name='weights'))

b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, _NUM_LABELS],
                                 mean=0,
                                 stddev=0.1,
                                 name='bias'))

# activation function
Y = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W) + b, name='activation')

# cost function i.e. sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_, logits=Y, name='loss_function')
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(_LEARNING_RATE)  # Formal derivation
train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

# cost function i.e. RMSE
# cross_entropy = tf.nn.l2_loss(Y - Y_, name="squared_error_cost")
# optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(_LEARNING_RATE)
# train_step = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

is_correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y, 1), tf.argmax(Y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct, tf.float32))

# init
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(_NUM_EPOCHS):
    # data
    batch_X, batch_Y = import_data(FILENAME)
    # train
    train_data = {X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y}
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)
    a, c = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=train_data)        
    print(str(i) + ": accuracy:" + str(a) + " loss: " + str(c))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem here:

```
>>> dataset[:, 8].shape
(768,)
```

TensorFlow is expecting an array of shape `(768,1)` and not `(768,)` as the error references:

```
Cannot feed value of shape (768,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

The difference between the two shapes is somewhat small and Numpy would normally broadcast these for you in many circumstances, but TF won't. See the difference between those two shapes [in this question with a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570756/difference-between-these-array-shapes-in-numpy).

Luckily in your case the solution is very simple. You can use [`np.expand_dims()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to turn your `(768,)` vector into a `(768,1)` vector, as demonstrated here:

```
>>> np.array([5,5,5]).shape
(3,)
>>> np.expand_dims(np.array([5,5,5]), axis=1).shape
(3, 1)
```

In your `import_data` function, simply change the return line to

```
return dataset[:, 0:8], np.expand_dims(dataset[:, 8], axis=1)
```

Edit: I like the above because `np.expand_dims` is a little more explicit, but there's another way that is equally simple, and others might think it's more clear---just depends on what you're used to. Figured I'd include it for completeness. The difference between a `(N,)` and `(N,1)` array is the first holds values in a 0-dimensional array `np.array([5, 5, 5])` while the second holds values in a 1-dimensional array `np.array([[5],[5],[5]])`. You can turn your 0-d array into a 1-d array by adding a bracket around it; but then it's a row and not a column, so it needs to be transposed. So here's the two suggested ways together; `B` is the new suggestion, `C` is the above suggestion:

```
>>> A = np.array([5,5,5])
>>> B = np.array([A]).T
>>> C = np.expand_dims(A, axis=1)
>>> A; A.shape
array([5, 5, 5])
(3,)
>>> B; B.shape
array([[5],
       [5],
       [5]])
(3, 1)
>>> C; C.shape
array([[5],
       [5],
       [5]])
(3, 1)
```

Edit2: Also TensorFlow itself has a [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) function.