# What is the difference between a numpy array of size (100, 1) and (100,)?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two variables coming from diffrent functions and the first one `a` is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(100,)
```

while the other one `b` is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(100, 1)
```

If I try to correlate them via:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
p, r= pearsonr(a, b)
```

I get:

```
    r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between a and b?
2. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between these array shapes in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570756/difference-between-these-array-shapes-in-numpy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question's answer**: `a` is a vector, and `b` is a matrix. Look at this stackoverflow link for more details: [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r)

**Second question's answer**:

I think converting one to the other form should just work fine. For the function you provided, I guess it expects vectors, hence just reshape b using `b = b.reshape(-1)` which converts it to a single dimensions (a vector). Look at the below example for reference:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.stats import pearsonr
>>> a = np.random.random((100,))
>>> b = np.random.random((100,1))
>>> print(a.shape, b.shape)
(100,) (100, 1)
>>> p, r= pearsonr(a, b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Appdata\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 3042, in pearsonr
    r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> b = b.reshape(-1)
>>> p, r= pearsonr(a, b)
>>> print(p, r)
0.10899671932026986 0.280372238354364
```

Answer (score 4):

(100,1) is 2d array of rows of length 1 like = `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]` and second one is 1d array `[1, 2, 3, 4 ]`

```
a1 = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
a2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call the reshape function on the first one to `.reshape((100,1))` Reshape will change the "shape" property of the np array which will make the 1D array [1,2,3, ..., 100] to a 2D array [[1],[2],[3],...[100]]

Comment: In order to provide a better answer, you should explain why.