# TFP Linear Regression yhat=model(x_tst) - doesn't work for other data

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

**I cannot see the difference between what I am doing and the working Google TFP example, whose structure I am following. What am I doing wrong/should I be doing differently?**

[Setup: Win 10 Home 64-bit 20H2, Python 3.7, TF2.4.1, TFP 0.12.2, running in Jupyter Lab]

I have been building a model step by step following the example of TFP [Probabilistic Layers Regression](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression). The Case 1 code runs fine, but my parallel model doesn't and I cannot see the difference that might cause this

```
yhat = model(x_tst)
```

to fail with message `Input 0 of layer sequential_14 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (2019,)` (which is the correct 1D size of x_tst)

For comparison: Google's load_dataset function for the TFP example returns `y, x, x_tst`, which are all np.ndarray of size 150, whereas I read data from a csv file with pandas.read_csv, split it into train_ and test_datasets and then take 1 col of data as independent variable 'g' and dependent variable 'redz' from the training dataset.

I know x, y, etc. need to be np.ndarray, but one does not create ndarray directly, so I have...

```
x = np.array(train_dataset['g'])
y = np.array(train_dataset['redz'])
x_tst = np.array(test_dataset['g'])
```

where x, y, x_tst are all 1-dimensional - just like the TFP example.

The model itself runs

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1)),
])

# Do inference.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss=negloglik)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, verbose=False);
```

(and when plotted gives the expected output for the google data - I don't get this far):

[image]

But, per the example when I try to "profit" by doing `yhat = model(x_tst)` I get the dimensions error given above.

What's wrong?

(If I try mode.predict I think I hit a known bug/gap in TFP; then it fails the assert)

**Update - Explicit Reshape Resolves Issue**

The hint from Frightera led to further investigation: x_tst had shape (2019,)

Reshaping by `x_tst = x_tst.rehape(2019,1)` resolved the issue. Is TF inconsistent in its requirements or is there some good reason that the explicit final dimension 1 was required? Who knows. At least predictions can be made now.

Comment: Can you add the shapes of the datasets of yours?

Comment: @Frightera all 1D, just like the TFP example (I have added the info to the post as well)

Comment: TFP examples are like (150,1). Try to reshape your data maybe?

Comment: @Frightera - see update. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question [Difference between numpy.array shape (R, 1) and (R,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053050/difference-between-numpy-array-shape-r-1-and-r), the OP asked for the difference between (R,) and (R,1) but the answers given did not address this specific point.

Similarly in this question [Difference between these array shapes in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570756/difference-between-these-array-shapes-in-numpy)

I believe the answer lies in the [numpy glossary](https://numpy.org/devdocs/glossary.html#:%7E:text=The%20trailing%20comma%20distinguishes%20a,of%20array%20elements%20the%20same.), where it says of (n,) that

> A parenthesized number followed by a comma denotes a tuple with one
> element. The trailing comma distinguishes a one-element tuple from a
> parenthesized n.

Which, naturally, echoes the Python statements concerning tuples  [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple)

Thus an array of shape (R,) is a tuple describing an array as being 1D of a certain extent R, where the comma is appended to distinguish the tuple (R,) from the non-tuple (R).

However, for a 1D array, there is no sense of row or column ordering; (R,1) is R rows by 1 column, but (1, R) would be 1 row of R columns, and though it shouldn't matter to a 1D iterator either it does or the iterator doesn't correctly recognise ( ,) and thinks it is 2D. (i.e. I don't know the technical details of that part, but these seem to be the only options that account for the behaviour.)

This issue is unrelated to the indeterminacy of size that occurs in tensor definition in Tensorflow. In the context of Tensorflow, Tensors (arrays) may have indeterminate shapes, so that more data may be added along a certain axis as processing occurs, e.g. in batches, in which case the initial Tensor shape includes a leading None to indicate where array expansion is expected to occur. (See e.g. tensor's shape [here](https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/))